# Designing a Gabor filter bank in the Fourier domain

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft, gabor-filter

I am trying to design a gabor filter bank in the Fourier domain using the following code in Matlab:

```
for i=1:u
 for j = 1:v
   theta =theta_list(j);
   w_1_x=(centerFreq(1,i)*((m+1)/2)*cos(theta)); % size of filter and image is m-by-n 
   w_1_y=(centerFreq(2,i)*((n+1)/2)*sin(theta));
   w_2_x=(-centerFreq(1,i)*((m+1)/2)*cos(theta));
   w_2_y=(-centerFreq(2,i)*((n+1)/2)*sin(theta));
   sigma=sqrt((w_1_x)^2+(w_1_y)^2);
   sigma_H=sigma/(2*pi);
   gF=fspecial('gaussian', [m,n], sigma_H);
   gFilter1=circshift(gF, [round(w_1_x), round(w_1_y)]);
   gFilter2=circshift(gF, [round(w_2_x), round(w_2_y)]);
   gaborArray1{i,j} = 0.5*gFilter1+0.5*gFilter2;
   gaborArray2{i,j} = 0.5*1i*gFilter1-0.5*1i*gFilter2;
   gaborFilterBank{i,j}=gaborArray1{i,j}+1i.*gaborArray2{i,j};
 end
end
```

However, when I transform the filter to the image domain using the following code and visualize the phase map of the filter:

```
filter=ifft2(ifftshift(gaborFilterBank{i,j}));
phase=zeros(m, n);
for p=1:m
 for q=1:n
    phase(p,q)=atan(imag(filter(p,q)/real(filter(p,q)));
  end
end
figure, imshow(phase, []);
```

I get strange patterns at the center of the filter (as shown in the attached figure). Would you please let me know what is wrong with my code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Instead of multiplying the center coordinates by [(m+1)/2, (n+1)/2], I should have multiplied them by [m, n]. More specifically, instead of:

```
w_1_x=(centerFreq(1,i)*((m+1)/2)*cos(theta)); % size of filter and image is m-by-n 
w_1_y=(centerFreq(2,i)*((n+1)/2)*sin(theta));
w_2_x=(-centerFreq(1,i)*((m+1)/2)*cos(theta));
w_2_y=(-centerFreq(2,i)*((n+1)/2)*sin(theta));
```

It should be:

```
w_1_x=(centerFreq(1,i)*m*cos(theta)); % size of filter and image is m-by-n 
w_1_y=(centerFreq(2,i)*n*sin(theta));
w_2_x=(-centerFreq(1,i)*m*cos(theta));
w_2_y=(-centerFreq(2,i)*n*sin(theta));
```